# Append specific output from ubuntu terminal in a csv file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing, csv

[image: here]

Above is the output of my command. I want to save the highlighted output into a csv file in append mode. They should be in the same row but in different columns. My final csv file should be like this

```
6733 1900
```

and if I again run this command then it should be appended in the next row, like this

```
6733 1900 

6733 1900
```

Answer (score 1):

CSV is usually comma-separated. However, TSV is tab-separated.

```
$ cat summary
 Type                Name                   # reqs    50%     60%     75%     80%     90%    95%    98%      99%     99.9%   99.99%    100%
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GET                 /                        6733    860    1200    1400    1500    1900   3000   3400     3700     5900    6900     6900
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 None               Aggregated               6733    860    1200    1400    1500    1900   3000   3400     3700     5900    6900     6900
```

Based on the provided image, it looks like you want to get the 3rd and 8th whitespace-delimited fields, from the line of output starting with "GET"

```
$ cat summary | grep "^ GET" | awk '{print $3"\t"$8}' >> output.tsv
```

```
6733    1900
```

Using `>>` will append stdout to an output file.

Alternatively, if you want to view the output *and* save to a file, you can pipe to `tee -a` instead.

Comment: Thank you @shiftF5. Your solution works great. Just did it by doing a little change in grep command. `cat summary | grep -i 'GET' | awk '{print $3","$8}' >> output.csv` . Sorry for late reply.

Comment: Ah, I did not notice the space prior to "GET", corrected. Hope that helped.

Comment: You can `grep pattern file` and let `cat` have a sleep (doubtless `awk` can also manage this by itself, but I don't know how)